# Postgres: Selecting from JSON array gives "invalid input syntax for type json"

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

The table `foo` has a column `data` which stores json as:

```
{ values: ["AR", "BR", "CR"] }
```

I want to select all rows where `bar.value` appears in foo.values. When I do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.id = foo.id
WHERE foo.data::jsonb->'values' @> bar.value::jsonb;
```

I get the error

```
[Code: , SQL State: 22P02]  ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
Detail: Token "BR" is invalid.
Where: JSON data, line 1: BR
```

Which i don't get if I replace `foo.value::jsonb` with `'"BR"'`.

Is there a solution for this? Or is there a better query even?